# @setup annotation and @env annotion eveluation

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I have question about when @setup is called and the @env annotions.  In my situation the @setup is being called no matter what the @env annotation is.
Seems that the @env annotation is eveluated after that @setup in Karate version 1.3.  Is this by desing?

---

```
    @SpringBootTest
    class CalendarBatchRunner {
        @Karate.Test
        Karate getApiTest() {
            return new Karate().relativeTo(getClass())
        }
    }
```

---

cb.feature

```
    @env=Unit,itg,cat
    Feature: Calendar Batch
    
        Background:
    
        
        @setup
        Scenario:
            * print '***** SETUP cb.feature ********'
            * json datesUnderTest = karate.properties['dates.under.test']
    
        Scenario Outline: Verify <holidayDate>
    
            * assert 1 == 1
            Examples:
                | karate.setup().datesUnderTest |
```

---

cb-validation.feature

```
    @env=prod
    Feature: Calendar Batch Validation
    
        Background: 
    
        @setup
        Scenario:
            * print '***** SETUP calendar-batch-validation.feature ********'
            * json datesUnderTest = karate.properties['dates.under.test']
    
        Scenario Outline: Validate Holiday: <holidayDate>
    
            * assert 1 == 2
    
            Examples:
                | karate.setup().datesUnderTest |
```

Regardless of the env the @setup is being called.  I.e. if env is prod the cb.feature @setup is being called and logging '***** SETUP cb.feature ********'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm if Karate 1.3.1 [fixes this](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2169)? Else would be great to get an issue logged with a way to replicate.

Comment: Version 1.3.1 fixed this issue.  Thanks Peter.